# How to quit the app through a button?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to provide a quit button. There are lot of solutions but not the a proper one. Please help

Comment: Providing a quit button will get your app rejected from the app store. Read the development guidelines.

Comment: See also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/can-an-ios-application-have-an-explicit-quit-button

Comment: I am actually developing an in-house app. SO I won't be submitting it to the app store...

Comment: Even if you don't care about the app store, the HIG still holds. Users expect certain behaviours, so to violate those behaviours is to violate user expectations. Plus, quit buttons take up screen real-estate, which is at a premium especially on a small screen.

Comment: What about the other solutions were not "proper"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed {
    exit(1);
}
```

ciao

please don't do it!!!

Answer (score 5):

From a UX standpoint, it's better to let your users quit by pressing the home button, rather than providing a close button.

From the [iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27):

> #### Don’t Quit Programmatically
>
> Never quit an iOS app programmatically because people tend to interpret this as a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it. iOS prohibits it.